Should Angular Form controls always be non-nullable?
Since Angular introduced typed and also non-nullable form controls, I often hear the advise:

"For all greenfield projects, please make controls always
non-nullable, like this:

With formbuilder:
   formGroupA = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
      User: [''],
   });

With FormControl constructor:
   formGroupB = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
      User: new FormControl<EntraIdUserEntity | null>(null, {nonNullable: true}),
   });

ie. this blog article states so.

If you are developing a form “on a greenfield site”, we recommend that
you set the nonNullable option to true for each control. This
simplifies working with the generated data because the types reflect
the actual input value. A normal input field, for example, always
generates an empty string or a string with values.

However, I do not think the advise is always valid, because in many scenarios a form should have initial values that are null:

The picture shows a form with two selections and both should not have any default value.
Therefore 'null' is the best initial value for those controls.
The same applies for many others:

Date pickers
Radio buttons
Custom elements
Tree state checkboxes

I understand that text fields should naturally start with an empty string '' and should be non-nullable because their initial value is "naturally" empty.
But in many other cases, 'null' represents reality most acurately.
Do you have some good counter arguments? :-)

Blogs are opinionated by nature. Nothing prevents you from creating nullable controls !
As you said, it can represent reality better, and not only that, but some applications (like the one I'm working on) require blank values to be different from null values : this means that blank values actually have a value that is neither null nor undefined.
Just a sidenote, you can also create a string control with a start value of null like so, if it can ever be of use :
form = this.fb.group({ username: [<string>null!, [Validators.required] })


Yes, I think the piece of code does not compile (at least for me). And: Can you explain better how a "blank" field can be neither null NOR undefined? This is not clear to me...

@NarenMurali It does not make sense to you, but can make sense to others. To be clear I agree with the fact that it goes against typings, but it can be used for very particular use cases. So no, I will not remove it, sorry !

@DavidMason "blank field" as used in my post refers to fields that have an empty string value (we call them "blancs" in my french company, which is the translation of "white")

The first answer is correct, blogs are expressing personal opinion.
Date, select, etc -> null is a good initial value.
Many datepickers will complain if you set '' as an initial value for the control, e.g: Kendo Date Picker.
You could take the approach of using this.fb.nonNullable only for controls that accept a string  as input, so that you can set the initial value to '' and have the control typed only to string.
But your real world explanation of few controls not accepting empty string is valid so that type must be <some type> | null
